# How did Asgard's army travel to Vanaheim in Thor: The Dark World

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

At the end of *Thor* (2011), Thor destroys the Bifrost. Hence Odin had to summon dark energy to send Thor to Earth in *The Avengers* (2012). Later in the same movie, Thor and Loki use Tesseract to go back to Asgard.

In *Thor: The Dark World*, how did the army get to Vanaheim to restore peace? Did they use Tesseract again or did they rebuild Bifrost? Is it mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thor and Heimdall repair the Rainbow Bridge with the power of the Tesseract as we see in *Thor: The Dark World Prelude* Issue 2.

[image: Thor and Heimdall walk the Asgardian Royal Palace talking about what worlds are in chaos and if they can prevent that at Vanaheim. They use the power of the Tesseract to fix the Bifrost]

This is also shown in *Thor: The Dark World* as we see Thor arrive using the Bifrost. Presumably the Asgardian army also used the Bifrost to get there.

[image: Thor arrives to Vanaheim using the Bifrost]